# While loop does not continue to If statement

Tags: python, loops

I'm new to Python and I am trying to figure out why my program will not run past the initial input.  Everything works fine until I input a number.  Then it just goes back to the beginning of the program.  The looped statement looks as follows:

```
 loop = 1
 choice = 0
 while loop == 1:
     choice = menu()
     if choice == 1:
        (List of commands)
     elif choice == 2:
        (List of commands)  etc...
     elif choice == 5:
        loop = 0
```

I'm a big noob so I bet this is a ridiculous question but I'm just stumped!

Comment: the etc... isn't actually in the program obviously!

Comment: how do you input the number? If the `menu()` gives `choice` 5, it certainly will exit the loop..

Comment: If choice is returned as a string ("5") then it wouldn't equal 5 and would thus not exit.  Much depends on what `menu()` looks like.

Comment: Does it work if you cast the return value of `menu()` to an `int`? i.e. `choice = int(menu())`?

Comment: debug your code by some print. for example `print choice` or `print type(choice)`. `5` is `int` and `'5'` is `str`

Comment: `menu()` is just a bunch of `print` statements, then at the end it is a return statement.  When I run the program it just skips all the functions in the loop and goes right to the end restarting the program.  I'm sorry if thats hard to understand as I said I'm new to Python and I'm trying my best to understand everything!

Comment: if I debug with print it will tell me what each equals at that point in the code correct? and I will try changing it to `choice = int(menu())`

Comment: The problem is in the code you haven't posted.

Comment: Changing `choice = int (menu())` got me farther along but I got a TypeError.  Essentially what the program is to do is be a simple calculator I'm trying different tutorials to help build my skills.  This is the error it has given me:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jeremy/Desktop/Python/test3", line 45, in <module>
    mul(input("Multiply this: "), input("by this: "))
  File "C:/Users/Jeremy/Desktop/Python/test3", line 29, in mul
    print (a, "*", b, "=", a * b)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

so i'm assuming its because the code is written all in 'str' instead of 'int'? if that makes sense.

Comment: I feel stupid, but I'm determined to figure this out.

Comment: It will add when I input add, however it does not add the numbers together it just adds them like this 1 + 1 = 11.  SO, They are not coded as `int` but as `str`.  Would I be correct in saying this?

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'` mean you multiply like this '5'*'5', they are `str` but not int 5*5.

and `'1'+'1' = '11'` but `1 + 1 = 2`

So you should change **str** to **int**

Answer (score 0):

```
NO_ACTION, SMTH_ACTION, SMTH_OTHER_ACTION, EXIT_ACTION = 0,1,2,3
choice = NO_ACTION
while True:
    choice = int(menu()) # python strong typed!

    if choice is SMTH_ACTION:
        (List of commands)

    elif choice is SMTH_OTHER_ACTION:
        (List of commands)  etc...

    elif choice is EXIT_ACTION:
       break
```

No exit flag needed - use `break` keyword.
Don't use "magic numbers" - define constants.

Comment: `def add (a,b):
    print (a, "+", b, "=", (a + b)

#this subtracts two numbers given
def sub (a,b):
    print (b, "-", a, "=", b - a)

#this multiplies two numbers given
def mul (a,b):
    print (a, "*", b, "=", a * b)

#this divides two numbers given
def div (a,b):
    print (a, "/", b, "=", a / b)`

so I shouldn't define my functions like this then, I should do it 

`NO_ACTION, SMTH_ACTION, etc = 0,1,2,3` and it will take each of those and link it with the corresponding number.  NO_ACTION = 0 SMTH_ACTION = 1 etc.  Again sorry for being a noob!  Gotta learn through trial and error!

Comment: sorry for the sloppy code, it didn't come out the way I expected!

Comment: @Jeremy Smith, place descriptions of functions to [docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) :)

Comment: And @Jeremy Smith, use string formatting: `print('%s + %s = %s' % (a, b, a+b))`